# Starting Kafka Broker with SSL give SSLHandShakeError

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I'm trying to start a Kafka Broker using SSL, so I created the following bash to create my certificates:

```
#!/bin/bash
        #Step 1
        keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -validity 365 -genkey
        #Step 2
        openssl req -new -x509 -keyout ca-key -out ca-cert -days 365
        keytool -keystore server.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert
        keytool -keystore client.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert
        #Step 3
        keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -certreq -file cert-file
        openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in cert-file -out cert-signed -days 365 -CAcreateserial -passin pass:123456
        keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert
        keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -import -file cert-signed
```

All certs was generated without error, so I configured in my kafka the following:

```
#########SSL CONFIGURATION###############
ssl.keystore.location=/home/ronaldo.lanhellas/Downloads/kafka-with-cert/certs/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=123456
ssl.key.password=123456
ssl.truststore.location=/home/ronaldo.lanhellas/Downloads/kafka-with-cert/certs/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=123456
ssl.client.auth=required
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
#ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
#ssl.cipher.suites=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
```

But when I try to start my broker I got the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common for configuration A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings can't connect to a server SSLEngine created with those settings.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:71)
    ... 18 more
```

And to help me I enabled Debug SSL:

```
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA
Extension extended_master_secret
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
main, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
main, called closeOutbound()
main, closeOutboundInternal()
main, called closeInbound()
main, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
main, called closeOutbound()
main, closeOutboundInternal()
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeInbound()
main, fatal error: 80: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
```

Reading about this I found a post that said: "Exists a problem with cipher in JDK 1.8_192 and later (I'm using 1.8_232)", so the workaround should be a downgrade but I don't think this is a good solution, and I didn't try yet.

Any tips to solve this problem?

**Edit 1**
In my java.security file I got following:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
    EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
```

And yes, I'm using OpenJDK

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
```

**Solution**

I just regenerate the certificates using the following guide: https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309. And after import to a keystore and a truststore.

Comment: Are you sure you have cipher_suites commented out? The connection attempt is using that list, which doesn't include any ciphersuites that can use a cert containing a DSA (aka DSS) key, which is what you created. AFAICT there is no Oracle release of 8u232; is this OpenJDK and if so from where/built by whome? What is the setting of `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` in `JRE/lib/security/java.security` ?

Comment: PS: since j7 `keytool -gencert` can create a CA-signed cert so if you prefer you can do without openssl.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I edited my post to answer your question about jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms, And yes I have sure that cipher_suites is commented out

Comment: Then I don't understand why your connection is not using DSA/DSS suites. But the method you link creates an RSA key instead of DSA and thus works. You could have done the same thing more simply by adding `-keyalg RSA` to `keytool ... -genkey`

Answer (score 1):

Solution

I just regenerate the certificates using the following guide: https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309. And after import to a keystore and a truststore.